# Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am developing an application to schedule periodic backups, that make full, differential and log backups.

Log backup is each 15 minutes, differential each 6 hours, and full backup each 24 hours.

At first it works fine, but when it had to do the full backup, I get the error:

> Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

At time of full backup, the application does the differential al log backup, I don't control if I will do a full backup, avoid the differential and log backup, so sometimes the log and differential backup can be done first and sometimes after the full backup (the application is multithread).

The application runs on the same server as the SQL Server. The database is about 900MB, and a full backup takes about 30-40 seconds.

I am using filestream too.

How could I try to ensure that the application does the backups without this problem?

I have read in another similar questions that I could solve the problem increasing the timeout in the command, but they doesn't explain if this will have some side effect or not.

I am using SqlCommand. My main doubt is that if I set a very high timeout value, it could have some bad side effect, if I should to have some consideration, because if the default value is 30 seconds, I guess it is for a reason.

Comment: if you execute the backup command exactly as the application is programmed to, but from management studio, does it execute successfully? Add the backup command to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Not everything has a hard and fast rule. 30 seconds is somewhat an arbitrary value while still being relatively reasonable, but Microsoft could've just as easily picked 45 seconds or 60 seconds or even 90 seconds, and the general outcome would've been the same, in most cases. But some value needs to be chosen, because if every SqlCommand had an infinite timeout, then there would be more occurrences of server resource contention and potentially increased waits due to locking.

The value of the timeout is for you to choose based on your use cases. Some people might have a database systems that can't tolerate backups that take minutes to run at any point (because they have more important things they want to prioritize the resources to - though backups are pretty important, as an aside), so they would prefer for it to fail in that case as opposed to continuing to run.

The point is, it's up to the developer to choose what's more important in each instance of a SqlCommand. In your case, you need to choose between giving the backup a reasonable chance to finish (which generally 30 seconds is going to be a pretty low cutoff for a full database backup) or not taking up too many server resources when that command runs. I'd recommend trying increasing it to a minute or even a couple of minutes and test it. You'll likely find no negative impact whatsoever by doing so in this specific case. (For reference, I've ran full backups that take an hour+ to complete before.)

Also, to clarify one point, the command timeout of a SqlCommand is a client side timeout configuration. Timeouts are generally something that occur on the client side, and when they occur they issue a cancellation of the query they were executing on the server. SQL Server doesn't *usually* generate timeouts on its end (except for queries executed across a linked server being one exception that I can think of to this).

Answer (score 2):

Well if everything starts at the same time, then you might encounter issues. Let's put your backups schedule into a time graph table (sort of). It should look like this:

```
    18:00       19:00       20:00       21:00       22:00       23:00       00:00       01:00   ...
      |           |           |           |           |           |           |           |
      |--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|...
TLOG  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
DIFF  x                                                                       x
FULL                                                                          x
```

At the time your **FULL**, **DIFF** and **TLOG** backup collide you might run into timeout issues.

#### Possible Solution(s)

1. Instead of having the **FULL**, **DIFF** and **TLOG** backups run at the same time, try and offset/stagger them by 5 minutes:

   ```
        18:00       19:00       20:00       21:00       22:00       23:00       00:00       01:00   ...
          |           |           |           |           |           |           |           |
          |--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|...
    TLOG    x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
    DIFF   x                                                                       x
    FULL                                                                          x
   ```

   In this example:

   - TLOG backups run at xx:10, xx:25, xx:40, xx:55
   - DIFF backups run at xx:05 (every hour)
   - FULL backups run at 00:00 (once a day)
2. Omit the **DIFF** backup when the **FULL** occurs:

   ```
        18:00       19:00       20:00       21:00       22:00       23:00       00:00       01:00   ...
          |           |           |           |           |           |           |           |
          |--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|--|...
    TLOG  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x  x
    DIFF  x                                                                       -
    FULL                                                                          x
   ```

   In this example:

   - TLOG backups run at xx:00, xx:15, xx:30, xx:45
   - DIFF backups run at xx:00 (every hour; except 00:00 )
   - FULL backups run at 00:00 (once a day)

#### FileStream

Seeing as the database is using FileStream and backups have to be consistent with the data in the FileStream directory, you might be running into a time-out issue. Staggering the backup should ease the pressure on SQL Server to produce consistent Database/FileStream backups.